# Wkhtmltopdf no images

Tags: php, image-processing, wkhtmltopdf

wkhtmltopdf does not render images from other sites. I have discovered what many developers suggest just prefix an image file with :

```
file://
```

and add a full path. But this approach does not fit my needs. I need to render images from other site, because I have a separate image provider service.Also, I have tried --images flag.

Also I tried with google.com. But still I get pdf without any images.

```
xvfb-run wkhtmltopdf 'https://google.com' '/home/project/src/uploads/google.pdf'
```

P.S. I use wkhtmltopdf 0.12.3.2.

Comment: I have solved by adding additional tags : 

 xvfb-run -a -s "-screen 0 640x480x16" wkhtmltopdf http://www.google.com test.pdf

Answer (score 8):

Adding `-a -s "-screen 0 640x480x16"` as arguments for `xvfb-run` is indeed what it solved for me as well.

So as already suggested above, this does render images:

`xvfb-run -a -s "-screen 0 640x480x16" wkhtmltopdf google.com test.pdf`

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you! This solved the problem I was having with images not displaying in a PDF.  I was being thrown off by the error `libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to open swrast`. I believe the `swrast` error is just a warning that it's using software rendering instead of hardware rendering (which makes sense, since it's headless).

Answer (score 0):

yes, this solved my problem, here is my full command :

```
exec('xvfb-run -a -s "-screen 0 640x480x16" -- /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf --quiet --enable-local-file-access --page-size Letter /tmp/html.html /tmp/pdf.pdf');
```